# How to pass state properties from component to component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, state

I am currently learning React and I am trying to create a basic todo list app. I am facing an issue in the understanding of how passing data from component to component.

I need that when I add a task in the modal of my home component it gets added in the "pub" state of my public task component in order for the task to be rendered.

I joined the code of both components,

Hope someone can help me :)

```
function PublicTask (){

    const [pub,setPub] = useState([{id: 1, value : "test"},{id: 2, value : "test2"}]);

    function ToDoPublicItem() {
        
        const pubT =  pub.map(value =>{
            return(
                <div className= 'pubTask-item'>
                <li>{value.value}</li>
                </div>
            )
        });

        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    {pubT}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    
    }

    return(
        <div className= 'item-container'>
            <h2 style={{color:'white'}}>Public Tasks</h2>
            <ToDoPublicItem/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PublicTask;
```

---

```
function Home() {
    
    const [show,setShow] = useState(false);
    const [pubTask,setPubTask] = useState([]);

    function openModal() {
        setShow(true);
    }

    function Modal(){
        const[textTodo, setTextTodo] = useState('')

        const addItem = () => {
            const itemTopush = textTodo;
            pubTask.push(itemTopush);
        }

        return(      
            <div className='modal'>
                <div className = 'modal-title'>
                    <h2>ADD A TODO</h2> 
                    <hr></hr>
                </div>
                <div className= 'modal-body'>
                    <input type='text' onChange = {(e) => setTextTodo(e.target.value)}/>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="pub" value ='public'/>
                    <label Htmlfor="pub">Public</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="priv" value= 'private '/>
                    <label Htmlfor="riv">Private</label>
                    <hr></hr>
                    <Button id='button-add' size='large' style={{backgroundColor : 'white'}} onClick={()=> addItem()}>ADD</Button>
                    <hr></hr>
                    <Button id='button-close' size='large'  style={{backgroundColor : '#af4c4c'}} onClick= {()=> setShow(false)} >CLOSE</Button>
                </div>
            </div> 
            )
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h1 style={{textAlign:'center'}}>You are logged in !</h1>
            <div>
                <button id='button-logout' onClick = {() => firebaseApp.auth().signOut()}>Logout</button>
            </div>
            <div>
            <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add" size = 'large' onClick = {() => openModal()}>
               <Add/>
            </Fab>
                {show ? <Modal/> : <div></div>}

            </div>

            <div>
                <Router>
                    <div className='pub-container'>
                        <Link to='/publicTasks'>Public Tasks </Link>
                    </div>

                    <div className='ongo-container'>
                        <Link to='/onGoingTasks'>On Going Tasks </Link>
                    </div>

                    <div className='finish-container'>
                        <Link to='/finishedTasks'>Finished Tasks </Link>
                    </div>

                    <Route path='/publicTasks' component = {PublicTask}/>
                    <Route path='/onGoingTasks' component = {OngoingTask}/>
                    <Route path='/finishedTasks' component = {FinishedTask}/>

                </Router>

            </div>
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: (When presenting a contiguous piece of something pre-formatted, like source code, use a code block. I find it least troublesome to enclose it in lines containing just `~~~`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can share data between react components like this:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("test"); // data that you want to share

return (
<Parent data={value}> // pass data to parent in your child component
);

<h1>{this.props.data}</h1> // do something with the data in the parent component
```